# Can VLC Player goto FullScreen on a 2nd Display automatically?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get VLC to play on the second monitor on windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/87436/how-do-i-get-vlc-to-play-on-the-second-monitor-on-windows)

Hi folks,

I've been using VLC player on my mac (with a TV connected to that as a 2nd device) and when i hit Full Screen, it goes full screen on my tv (monitor #2).

Now, i've moved the mac into another room and replace it with a windows pc (win 7). I can't figure out how to make full screen auto goto the tv/display #2. It just goes full screen to the window the player is current in.

This means i need to drag the player to the tv, then click F. I know it's easy to do .. but i really liked the experience I had with the Mac.

So - can this be done on a PC version of VLC Player?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/87436/how-do-i-get-vlc-to-play-on-the-second-monitor-on-windows

Comment: Agreed - this is an exact duplicate. I've voted to close this.