# VLC launch parameters - specify which screen? video-x/video-y is ignored

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have 2 monitors, both 1920x1080.

I added some launch parameters to a VLC shortcut to get it to play a borderless/control less video that will automatically close when it finishes playing.

However, I need some control over which monitor it displays on. Right now it always displays full screen on my primary monitor. I have tried different values for video-x (0, -1920, 1920, etc) and it doesn't make a different for me. Video always launches in the primary monitor.

Is there a way to specify which window it play on?

Here is my current launch parameters:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --video-x=1920 --video-y=1080 --play-and-exit --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller "C:\myvideo.mp4"
```

Comment: [How do I get VLC to play on the second monitor on windows?](http://superuser.com/q/87436) suggests it is possible, but only when the 2nd display is to the **right** of the primary.

Comment: "It only works with the second output on the right. With it on the left, VLC seems to treat a negative window position as "use defaults". I haven't tried putting the second monitor above or below - presumably only one of those will work."